# How can I force write uppercase in search view?

Tags: java, android, searchview

I need to show all the letters in uppercase while the user is writing. I'm using this:
`android:inputType="textCapCharacters"`

But, when I push shift it turns to lowercase. I need something permanent.

Answer (score 0):

In code you can try this:

```
searchView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

just add android:textAllCaps="true" in the xml

example:

```
<android.support.v7.internal.widget.CompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:textAllCaps="true"/>
```